# Calling a function in the dictionary in parallel with obtaining a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I want to pass a key to a dictonary, get an attached to this key value and also call a function attached to same key if the function is present. I'm able to create something like this `d={'some_key':('value', func())}`, but it calls the function when the dictonary is initialized. I know that I can get a tuple with value and fucntion, check the length of this tuple and if the length equals 2 then call a function, but isn't there a more elegant way? Can I somehow make the functon activate only when I input a certain key without any other syntax? Just write `d[some_key]`, get a corresponding value and execute a function without any additional brackets.

Comment: {'some_key'=('value', func)} is probably what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to subclass `dict` to override the `__getitem__` method:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        a, b = super().__getitem__(index)
        return a, b()

def myfunc():
    return "Hello world"

mydict = MyDict({'a': (100, myfunc)})

print(mydict['a'])
```

outputs
`(100, 'Hello world')`

If you want to call the function and return the value:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        a, b = super().__getitem__(index)
        b()
        return a
```

Note that this is *very* unexpected behavior, so make sure your users know what will happen when they use this dictionary.

Comment: This gets my vote although perhaps *return a, b()* might be more useful

Comment: @LancelotduLac Yeah, just based on the last sentence of OP's post I think they might want just the value as a result and to execute the function as a side effect. Not sure though.

Comment: @rassar yes, that's exactly what I want to do.  Sorry that I couldn't make that more clear from the beginning. And your answer seems to be what I want. Thank you very much. Can't upvote it, but I would.